# User authentication through Office365

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

We're are about to build a new intranet system for our company, leaving SharePoint behind. The system will be built using Ruby on Rails. Since we're using Office365 for mail, calendar etc., we would like to authenticate our intranet users through Office365.

I'm aware of Microsoft Graph API, but I have a hard time figuring out of there is a possibility to authenticate users from a third-party application. Moreover, we would like to retrieve general information about the user, like profile picture and calendar information.

Is anybody knowledgeable about Microsoft Graph API and know if it's possible to achieve our goals using the API?

Comment: This is what 1000s of apps already do :) I'd start from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-overview

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. You would authenticate with Azure AD, which is in the 365 ecosystem.

I wrote (and answered) a detailed guide here:
[How to get the JWT (using OpenIdConnect) from HttpContext, and pass to Azure AD Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51509182/how-to-get-the-jwt-using-openidconnect-from-httpcontext-and-pass-to-azure-ad/51662749#51662749)

Note that this is the OpenIdConnect flow. I think the Saml2 flow is somewhat different.

Don't take my advice on storing the authentication codes or try to acquire the token silently - it ended up causing issues in production that weren't seen in test. Rather, just use the user object id as your key attribute.

The microsoft documentation on the topic is a little cerebral and abstract, so it'll take a little head scratching, but have a look at the samples mentioned in the post I linked above, they'll get you started.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, using Microsoft Graph is the right way to go about achieving the stated goals here.

There are quiet a few samples and tutorials provided on the [Microsoft identity platform code samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code) page that will teach how to build an app that calls [Microsoft Graph](https://graph.microsoft.com).